# Replace a string in one file with another string in another file

Tags: python, string, loops, dictionary, replace

I have a text file with several lines and want to replace strings that match certain values. I opted to use a dictionary to store the string-to-be-replaced as the key, and the replacement as the value. The dictionary was created by opening another text file (`template.txt`) that has two columns separated by a single Tab:

```
140101002   name44
140101030   name2
140101004   name3
140101058   name94
```

The input file (`input.txt`) has the following text:

```
...text... <!-- 140101002 --> ...text...
...text... <!-- 140101030 --> ...text...
...text... <!-- 140101004 --> ...text...
...text... <!-- 140101058 --> ...text...
```

and I want to search for the strings in the `template.txt` first column (like `140101002`) and replace it with the strings in the second column (like `name44`), so that the output file (`output.txt`) will look like this:

```
...text... <!-- name44 --> ...text...
...text... <!-- name2 --> ...text...
...text... <!-- name3 --> ...text...
...text... <!-- name94 --> ...text...
```

I have tried fixing this several times but cannot get it to work as intended:

```
fhand = open("/home/Documents/input.txt")
template = open("/home/Documents/template.txt")
fout = open("/home/Documents/output.txt","w")

# store the values in the dictionary:
templateDict = dict()
for line in template:
  lineList = line.split("\t")
  templateDict[lineList[0]] = lineList[1]

# replacement:
for line in fhand:
  for key in templateDict:
    if key in line2:
      line2 = line2.replace(key,templateDict[key])
  fout.write(line2) # write to output.txt

fout.close()
```

Comment: Is there any error you are getting ? Also i notice in the replacement loop, it should be line instead of line2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the first file into a dictionary, and then use `re.sub`:

```
import re
d = dict(re.split('\s+', i.strip('\n')) for i in open('filename.txt'))
content = [i.strip('\n') for i in open('filename2.txt')]
with open('results.txt', 'w') as f:
  f.write('\n'.join(re.sub('(?<=\<\!\-\-\s)\d+(?=\s\-\-\>)', lambda x:d[x.group()], i) for i in content))
```

Output:

```
...text... <!-- name44 --> ...text...
...text... <!-- name2 --> ...text...
...text... <!-- name3 --> ...text...
...text... <!-- name94 --> ...text...
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to strip the newline character before splitting the line into a list.

```
fhand = open("/home/Documents/input.txt")
template = open("/home/Documents/template.txt")
fout = open("/home/Documents/output.txt","w")

# store the values in the dictionary:
templateDict = dict()
for line in template:
  lineList = line.strip("\n").split("\t")
  templateDict[lineList[0]] = lineList[1]

# replacement:
for line in fhand:
  for key in templateDict:
    if key in line:
      line = line.replace(key,templateDict[key])
  fout.write(line) # write to output.txt

fout.close()
```